# xmltodict: unparsing raises ValueError('Document must have exactly one root.') - Python 3

Tags: python, json, xml, xmltodict, xml-to-json

**Objective is to convert JSON to XML** 
The code reads the JSON.txt, converts it into XML and writes it on to JSON_to_xml.txt. The below code returns a value error while unparsing giving an error that the file has multiple roots
even though it has a single root.

```
import xmltodict
import json
import sys

sys.stdout = open('JSON_to_XML.txt', 'w')
print(json.dumps(xmltodict.unparse(open("JSON.txt", "r").read()))) 
sys.stdout.close()
```

The content of the JSON.txt is as follows,

```
{"note": {"to": "Tove", "from": "Jani", "heading": "Reminder", "body": "Dont forget me this weekend!"}}
```

If I just copy the contents of the file to the script as shown below, it gives the output in proper XML format.

```
import xmltodict
import json
                                                                
print(json.dumps(xmltodict.unparse(
    {"note": {"to": "Tove", "from": "Jani", "heading": "Reminder", "body": "Dont forget me this weekend!"}})))
```

Your comments and suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your JSON.txt is probably a list (which is valid JSON) - can you put the first few lines into your question?

Comment: Hello Barny, The content of JSON:txt is same as the one on the second code block. Adding it here for your reference. {"note": {"to": "Tove", "from": "Jani", "heading": "Reminder", "body": "Dont forget me this weekend!"}}

Answer (score 0):

Here a dictionary is being passed into the function which is the correct way.

`print(json.dumps(xmltodict.unparse({"note": {"to": "Tove", "from": "Jani", "heading": "Reminder", "body": "Dont forget me this weekend!"}})))`

But in here the result of read() is a JSON string and is being passed into the function. So, before passing it should be converted into to dictionary.

```
import json
import sys

sys.stdout = open('JSON_to_XML.txt', 'w')
print(json.dumps(xmltodict.unparse(open("JSON.txt", "r").read()))) 
sys.stdout.close()
```

So the solution would be,

```
import json
import sys

# JSON to XML

f = open("JSON.txt")

sys.stdout = open('JSON_to_XML.txt', 'w')
print(json.dumps(xmltodict.unparse(json.load(f))))
sys.stdout.close()
```

Thank you, Mike: https://github.com/mpf82 for the help.